# I've added a remote called "mine", but my branch is showing up under "origin"

Tags: git

I am having a tough time figuring out what's going on. How can I checkout my `github.com:unphased/oh-my-zsh.vim`'s `master` branch?

I can see that one of my branches (which was badly named "master-mine", from an earlier attempt to do something similar to what i'm doing now, which is `git clone`ing the original repo rather than my own fork of the repo, and then attempting to add my own repo as another remote)

[image]

I know for a fact that robbyrussell's github repo has no `master-mine` branch.

I manually inserted the `[remote "mine"]` and `[branch "mine-master"]` entries myself.

I get the feeling that that was wrong and I should only be editing the config once those branches have been made.

I will now be just removing this and cloning my own repo and adding the original as a remote in order to merge in the upstream changes... I think I can manage that... but I'd like to know what happened here and how i might be able to clean this up next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fetch` part is wrong here:

```
[remote "mine"]
        url = git@github.com:unphased/oh-myu-zsh.git
        fetch= +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

It maps to the same remotes as origin. It should be:

```
        fetch= +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/mine/*
```

The part before `:` configures which branches on the remote that are supposed to be fetched. The part after `:` configures where in the local repository those are supposed to be copied to. So, since you call the remote repository `mine` in your repository, you should map the remote branches to a directory named `remotes/mine` in your repository.

In the future, when adding a remote, rather than editing the config directly, it is easier to use the `remote add` command:

```
git remote add mine git@github.com:unphased/oh-myu-zsh.git
```

Also, when adding a tracking branch, rather than editing the config directly, it is easier to do this (though you got that configuration right anyway):

```
git branch --track mine-master mine/master
```